# Get the first directory from URL with PHP

Tags: php, parsing, url

I have url in variable like this:

```
$url = 'http://mydomain.com/yep/2014-04-01/some-title';
```

Then what I want is to to parse the 'yep' part from it. I try it like this:

```
$url_folder = strpos(substr($url,1), "/"));
```

But it returns some number for some reason. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [**explode**](https://www.php.net/explode), Try this:

```
$url = 'http://mydomain.com/yep/2014-04-01/some-title';
$urlParts = explode('/', str_ireplace(array('http://', 'https://'), '', $url));
echo $urlParts[1];
```

[**Demo Link**](http://codepad.org/aM7hMXDb)

Comment: What if the url is just `www.domain.com/yep/2014-04-01/some-title` ?

Comment: Yes this seems to do the trick. Thanks. And I believe the www doesn't matter since it 'explodes' only the / parts

Comment: What if protocol is other that `http` or `https`, like `ftp`?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran OP isn't indicating that. But if you want to, then use `parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);` http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: @Manoj Yadav Infinite array, huh?

Comment: @Benio you can use `regex` also with `replace` function

Comment: @user1180790 brings up a great point about the flaw of allowing a visitor to force the server to store an infinite number of parts in an array, simply by manipulating the URL. This is definitely something to consider.

Answer (score 3):

Well, first of all the `substr(...,1)` will return to you everthing after position 1. So that's not what you want to do.

So `http://mydomain.com/yep/2014-04-01/some-title` becomes `ttp://mydomain.com/yep/2014-04-01/some-title`

Then you are doing `strpos` on everthing after position 1 , looking for the first `/` ... (Which will be the first `/` in `ttp://mydomain.com/yep/2014-04-01/some-title`). The function `strpos()` will return you the position (number) of it. So it is returning you the number `4`.

Rather you use `explode()`:

```
$parts = explode('/', $url);
echo $parts[3]; // yep
// $parts[0] = "http:"
// $parts[1] = ""
// $parts[2] = "mydomain.com"
// $parts[3] = "yep"
// $parts[4] = "2014-04-01"
// $parts[4] = "some-title"
```

Answer (score 1):

The **most efficient** solution is the [`strtok`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) function:

```
strtok($path, '/')
```

So complete code would be :

```
$dir = strtok(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH), '/')
```

Comment: my vote for the one line format

Answer (score 0):

Use [`parse_url`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.

```
$url = 'http://mydomain.com/yep/2014-04-01/some-title';
$url_array = parse_url($url);
preg_match('@/(?<path>[^/]+)@', $url_array['path'], $m);
$url_folder = $m['path'];
echo $url_folder;
```